# generate markdown comments within for loop

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, roxygen

I am trying to generate an HTML report, using knitr, based on an R script that has for loops.  I want to generate markdown comments from the comments within the for loop, but I am not sure if it's possible.

Here is simple example, this is in test.R:

```
for (i in 1:5) {
    ## This is a heading for `i`
    #' This is a comment for `i`
    print(i)    
}
```

Then i use spin to generate a Rmd file:
spin('test.R')

However, the Rmd file looks like the following.

````
```{r }
for (i in 1:5) {
    ## This is a heading for `i`
    #' This is a comment for `i`
    print(i)    
}
```
````

The markdown comments within the R chunk are not compiled into HTML. Is it possible?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: it sounds like you want to run some R code before conversion to Rmd, while as I understand it spin (followed by knit) does it the other way around. I think brew templates might help here.

Comment: I think you really mean _roxygen_ comments instead of _Markdown_ comments. As @baptiste mentioned, `brew` is more sophisticated for this kind of tasks (generate text from a loop).

Comment: @Yihui, you are correct. The R file contains roxygen comments, which I hope will be converted to Markdown comments after I run spin.

Comment: @baptiste, thanks for the suggestions, I'll check out brew.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you can obtain what you want in knitr with the code chunk option results='asis' that you can specify after "#+" in an R script to be passed to spin (but the code looks less "clean" than the interesting brew solution proposed by @daroczig):

```
#+ results='asis', echo = FALSE
for (i in 1:5) {
    cat("## This is a heading for ", i, "\n")
    cat("<!-- This is a comment for ", i, "-->\n")
    print(i)    
}
```

If this is test.R script and that you do spin("test.R"), the resulting md file will look like that :

```
## This is a heading for  1 
<!-- This is a comment for  1 -->
[1] 1
## This is a heading for  2 
<!-- This is a comment for  2 -->
[1] 2
## This is a heading for  3 
<!-- This is a comment for  3 -->
[1] 3
## This is a heading for  4 
<!-- This is a comment for  4 -->
[1] 4
## This is a heading for  5 
<!-- This is a comment for  5 -->
[1] 5
```

Comment: this allows me to put comments into the output, but the comments are not formatted using the Markdown notation.

Comment: What do you mean by comments formatted with the markdown notation ? Is it html comments that you are looking for ? If yes, you can do it the same way, see my edited example

Comment: (+1) I needed to include an additional `cat('\n')` after `print(i)` for headings 2 through 5 to be rendered as headings.

Answer (score 9):

One solution that worked for me, is provided by [how to create a loop that includes both a code chunk and text with knitr in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36373630/how-to-create-a-loop-that-includes-both-a-code-chunk-and-text-with-knitr-in-r). By using **Both** `results='asis'` and two spaces in front of `\n` at the end of each loop.

example:

**Without two spaces**:

````
```{r, results='asis'}
headers <- list("We","are","your","friends")
for (i in headers){
  cat("\n##H ", i, "  \n")
  cat("comment",i)
}
````

Output (html):

[image]

As you can see, the comments and headings get messed together

**Solution:**
**With two spaces**: `cat("  \n")` at the end of the loop

```
for (i in headers){
  cat("\n##H ", i, "\n")
  cat("comment",i)
  cat("  \n")# <---------------------------------
}
```

[image]

note: `cat("  \n")` needs to be at the very end, it does not work even if you plot or calculate something it in the loop.

Answer (score 6):

I have (re)implemented some features of `knitr` independently from @Yihui based on `brew` in my [pander](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#brew-to-pandoc) package that could help with such (and similar) issues if you do not want to run `brew` before `knit`ting. Quick demo:

```
> Pandoc.brew(text = "# Demonstrating a nice loop
+ <% for (i in 1:5) { %>
+ ## This is a header for <%=i%>
+ #' This is a comment for <%=i%>
+ <% } %>")

# Demonstrating a nice loop

## This is a header for _1_
#' This is a comment for _1_

## This is a header for _2_
#' This is a comment for _2_

## This is a header for _3_
#' This is a comment for _3_

## This is a header for _4_
#' This is a comment for _4_

## This is a header for _5_
#' This is a comment for _5_
```

Please note that you could also pass a file to `Pandoc.brew` (no need to use such troublesome setup with the `text` argument with real-life problems), and that you could also use `<% ... %>` tags for e.g. conditionals (like showing or not rendering part of a report). And most importantly: there is a huge difference between `<% ... %>` (unprocessed R commands) and `<%= ... %>` (results are processed by `pander`) tags. The latter means that all returned R objects are transformed to Pandoc's markdown, e.g.:

```
> Pandoc.brew(text = "# Demonstrating a conditional
+ <% for (i in 1:5) { %>
+ ## This is a header for <%=i%>
+ <% if (i == 3) { %>
+ Hey, that's **almost** <%=pi%>, that's between <%=3:4%>! Wanna fit a model to _celebrate_?
+ <%= lm(mpg ~ hp, mtcars) %>
+ <% }} %>")
# Demonstrating a conditional

## This is a header for _1_

## This is a header for _2_

## This is a header for _3_

Hey, that's **almost** _3.142_, that's between _3_ and _4_! Wanna fit a model to _celebrate_?

--------------------------------------------------------------
     &nbsp;        Estimate   Std. Error   t value   Pr(>|t|) 
----------------- ---------- ------------ --------- ----------
     **hp**        -0.06823    0.01012     -6.742   1.788e-07 

 **(Intercept)**     30.1       1.634       18.42   6.643e-18 
--------------------------------------------------------------

Table: Fitting linear model: mpg ~ hp

## This is a header for _4_

## This is a header for _5_
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I was hoping to avoid using too many explicit tags in the R code, but it's good to know there is a work around.