# How to iterate in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

i need to do the following

```
for (j in 1:n){

´´´{r}
print(list1[[j]])
´´´
$//$
$//$
$//$
´´´{r}
print(list2[[j]])
´´´

}
```

That is I need to iterate over code chunks is R markdown.

How can i do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop in R markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33269675/loop-in-r-markdown)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `results='asis` chunck option:

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---


```{r, results='asis', echo = FALSE}
n <- 3
list1 <- lapply(1:n,function(i) LETTERS[i])
list2 <- lapply(1:n,function(i) i)
for (j in 1:n){
cat(list1[[j]],'\n\n')
cat('$//$ \n\n')
cat(list2[[j]],'\n <br> <br> <br>\n')
}
```
````

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, it runs. but for some reason cat('\n') doesnot produce any empty line. do you know why that could be ?

Comment: you can add `<br>` to force new line, see my edit

Comment: hmm <br> does not work (i'm doing pdf)

Comment: I don't know better for pdf than `cat('.   \n')}`, interested to know if you find a solution

Comment: yes i tell you if i find it out

Comment: i know it: it's cat("\n \\ \n")
(i gues that cat(..) just accepts Latex and \\ is latex for empty row

Comment: it is however sometimes ambious to me how many \ to use. so for you it might also be cat("\n \ \n") or cat("\n \ \\ \n")