# Display output of knitr in rmarkdown loop

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kableextra

I know from [Loop in R markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33269675/loop-in-r-markdown) that the `asis` parameter in a markdown chunk will print the output of a loop.  I want to render the same designed table for several variables and can't seem to figure out how to do that when using `knitr`.  In this example, I want to see three tables, each with one row of `mtcars`.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Matt"
date: '2022-08-13'
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)
```


```{r, results = 'asis'}
for( i in 1:3 ){
 knitr::kable( mtcars[i,] , 
   caption = i ) %>%
   kable_paper( "hover" , full_width = F )
}
```
````

[image]

Comment: You need to print the output of calling `kable`

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be creating the expression for tables in the for loop as string literals then simply paste them with `knitr::knit(text = ...)`

````
```{r create_tables, include=FALSE}

multiple_tables <- rep("", 3)

for( i in 1:3 ){
  
  multiple_tables[i] <- paste0(
    "```{r echo=FALSE}\n",
    "knitr::kable( mtcars[", i, ",], caption = ", i, ") %>%
     kable_paper( \"hover\" , full_width = F )",
    "\n```\n"
  )
  
}

```


`r paste(knit(text = multiple_tables), collapse = '\n')`
````