# Create a loop that includes both a code chunk and text

Tags: r, loops, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to figure out how to create a loop that inserts some text into the *rmarkdown* file, and then produces the graph or table that corresponds to that header. The following is how I picture it working:

````
for(i in 1:max(month)){
### `r month.name[i]` Air quaility

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(airquality[airquality$Month == 5,])
```
}
````

This ofcourse just prints the for loop as text, if i surround the for loop with r`` I would just get an error.

I want the code to produce an rmd file that looks like this:

#### May Air Quality

Plot

#### June Air Quality

Plot

and so on and so forth.

Any ideas?  I cannot use latex because I at my work they do not let us download exe files, and I do not know how to use latex anyways. I want to produce a word document.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61330051  doesn't seem to have anything to do with spaces, moreso just putting everything into one, one-line `cat` statement

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can embed the markdown inside the loop using `cat()`.

Note: you will need to set `results="asis"` for the text to be rendered as markdown. 
Note well: you will need two spaces in front of the `\n` new line character to get knitr to properly render the markdown in the presence of a plot out.

````
# Monthly Air Quality Graphs
```{r pressure,fig.width=6,echo=FALSE,message=FALSE,results="asis"}

attach(airquality)
for(i in unique(Month)) {
  cat("  \n###",  month.name[i], "Air Quaility  \n")
  #print(plot(airquality[airquality$Month == i,]))
  plot(airquality[airquality$Month == i,])
  cat("  \n")
}
```
````

Comment: WoW thats super helpfull (please mark as correct answer) - it also answers this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178831/generate-markdown-comments-within-for-loop

Comment: Where on earth is that "2 spaces in front of \n" documented?

Comment: I try this solution in my R Notebook and get

May Air Quality

June Air Quality

plot
plot

i.e., my text outputs are all jammed together in one block and then the graphs come along.   Anyone know what's up with that?

Comment: One drawback might be that we cannot do cross-reference now.

Comment: Great answer. It can probably be helpful to use multiline strings and the glue package if one is trying to get even closer to the „feel“ of actually looping around some longer markdown text: cat(glue("..."))

Comment: I've also seen this documented similarly here. 

https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/results-asis.html

Comment: I have the same issue as David Kaufmann, the titles are all together, and then the plots all together.

Comment: This is really cool! Thanks for sharing. You'll need to wrap the plot in print() to make the same solution to work for ggplot2.

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59698183/4742889), you could also make use of the [pander](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander) package:

````
# Monthly Air Quality Graphs
```{r pressure2, fig.width=6, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, results="asis"}
library(pander)
for (i in unique(airquality$Month)) {
   # Inserts Month titles
   pander::pandoc.header(month.name[i], level = 3)
   # Section contents
   plot(airquality[airquality$Month == i,])
   # adding also empty lines, to be sure that this is valid Markdown
   pander::pandoc.p('')
   pander::pandoc.p('')
}
```
````

Comment: For me, this should be the answer due to simplicity. Managing `cat('  \n')` everywhere proved cumbersome and was causing some errors in an entire document if it was not positioned correctly in one section.

Comment: @andschar Could you have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56983105/5784831)? It seems, you suggestion gets close, but I still face problems with the leaflet map. (And I am not sure, whether {.tabset} works with pander.) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Under some conditions I find it helpful to **write a loop that writes chunk code** rather than **write a chunk that runs a loop**. Weird solution but it has worked for me beautifully in the past when a bare bones set of chunks is all I need. For your `airquality` case it would look like this:

````
## model chunk ##

# ## May Air Quality
# ```{r May}
# 
# plot(airquality[airquality$Month == 5,])
#
# ```

# all months in airquality
aqmonths <- c("May",
            "June",
            "July",
            "August",
            "September")

for (m in aqmonths) {
  cat(
    paste0(
      "## ", m, " Air Quality",
      "\n\n",
      "```{r ", m, "}",
      "\n\n",
      "plot(airquality[airquality$Month == ", match(m, months), ",])",
      "\n\n",
      "```",
      "\n\n"
    )
  )
}
````

This will print code for all 5 chunks to the console, and then I can copy and paste into a .Rmd document. It is possible to include any chunk options such as captions or `fig` arguments in the chunk-writing loop as well. Depending on what else you try to bring in, using functions like `match()` as in the example is often helpful.

**Pros:** Preserves ability to use cross-references and set individual captions or options.

**Cons:** Making changes to all chunks usually requires re-copying the entire output of the chunk-writing loop, which can be tiresome and a bit unwieldy.

Comment: I like this answer as it works with all types of plots and complicated documents. I suggest that instead of copy pasting, you run the code you created above in an R-file, and add 

     sink("output_from_print_code.Rmd")

which will write the entire code in there, from which you can just load it into your main R-markdown document by adding the chunk:   


     ```{r, child=c('output_from_print_code.Rmd')}
     ```

Comment: I'd love such a solution, but working strait in the Rmarkdown universe. Having a loop creating a chunk allows to change chunk options conditionally. E.g fig.width , ...

Answer (score 2):

What about reusing the chunks inside a loop using <<label>> as described here: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/reuse-chunks.html

Label your chunk, set eval=F

````
 ```{r my_chunk, echo=FALSE, eval=F}
plot(airquality[airquality$Month == 5,])
```
````

Then loop

```
for(i in 1:max(month)){
<<my_chunk>>
}
```