# R Markdown, output test results in loop

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm looking for a nicely formated markdown output of test results that are produced within a for loop and structured with headings. For example

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000),
           y = rnorm(1000),
           z = rnorm(1000))

for (v in c("y","z")) {
  cat("##", v, " (model 0)\n")
  summary(lm(x~1, df))

  cat("##", v, " (model 1)\n")
  summary(lm(as.formula(paste0("x~1+",v)), df))
}
```

whereas the output should be

### y (model 0)

```
Call:
lm(formula = x ~ 1, data = df)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.8663 -0.6969 -0.0465  0.6998  3.1648 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -0.05267    0.03293    -1.6     0.11

Residual standard error: 1.041 on 999 degrees of freedom
```

### y (model 1)

```
Call:
lm(formula = as.formula(paste0("x~1+", v)), data = df)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.8686 -0.6915 -0.0447  0.6921  3.1504 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -0.05374    0.03297  -1.630    0.103
y           -0.02399    0.03189  -0.752    0.452

Residual standard error: 1.042 on 998 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.0005668, Adjusted R-squared:  -0.0004346 
F-statistic: 0.566 on 1 and 998 DF,  p-value: 0.452
```

### z (model 0)

and so on...

There are several results discussing parts of the question like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33269675/loop-in-r-markdown?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36373630/how-to-create-a-loop-that-includes-both-a-code-chunk-and-text-with-knitr-in-r/36381976#36381976) suggesting the `asis`-tag in combination with the `cat`-statement. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178831/generate-markdown-comments-within-for-loop) includes headers.

Closest to me request seems to be [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903792/r-markdown-output-test-results-htest-when-chunk-option-results-asis?noredirect=1&lq=1) from two years ago. However, even though highly appreciated, some of suggestions are deprecated like the `asis_output` or I can't get them to work in general conditions like the `formattable` suggestion (e.g. with`lm`-output). I just wonder -- as two years have past since then -- if there is a modern approach that facilitates what I'm looking for.

Comment: Is the output that you're showing here how you want each model output formatted? Or is there something else you want to print for each model?

Comment: I wish for the nicely formated output of a simple print or print.summary statement of a statistical test-object. I have no need for additional information printed alongside this output. But I do have R code before and below the loop that I also wish to include in a rendered document.

Comment: I found another solution @Tom, I think this is what you really want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Solution Type 1

You could do a `capture.output(cat(.))` approach with some `lapply`-looping. Send the output to a file and use `rmarkdown::render(.)`.

This is the R code producing a `*.pdf`.

````
capture.output(cat("---
title: 'Test Results'
author: 'Tom & co.'
date: '11 10 2019'
output: pdf_document
---\n\n```{r setup, include=FALSE}\n
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)\n
mtcars <- data.frame(mtcars)\n```\n"), file="_RMD/Tom.Rmd")  # here of course your own data

lapply(seq(mtcars), function(i) 
  capture.output(cat("# Model", i, "\n\n```{r chunk", i, ", comment='', echo=FALSE}\n\
                   print(summary(lm(mpg ~ ", names(mtcars)[i] ,", mtcars)))\n```\n"),
                 file="_RMD/Tom.Rmd", append=TRUE))

rmarkdown::render("_RMD/Tom.Rmd")
````

### Produces:

[image]

## Solution Type 2

When we want to automate the output of multiple model summaries in the rmarkdown itself, we could chose between **1.** selecting chunk option `results='asis'` which would produce code output but e.g. `# Model 1` headlines, or **2.** to choose not to select it, which would produce **Model 1** but destroys the code formatting. The solution is to *use* the option and combine it with inline code that we can `paste()` together with another `sapply()`-loop within the `sapply()` for the models.

In the main `sapply` we apply *@G.Grothendieck's* venerable [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46616150/6574038) to nicely substitute the `Call:` line of the output using `do.call("lm", list(.))`. We need to wrap an `invisible(.)` around it to avoid the unnecessary `sapply()` output `[[1]] [[2]]...` of the empty lists produced.

I included a `". "` into the `cat()`, because leading white space like `` `    this` `` will be rendered to `this` in lines 6 and 10 of the summary outputs.

This is the rmarkdown script producing a `*pdf` that can also be executed ordinary line by line:

````
---
title: "Test results"
author: "Tom & co."
date: "15 10 2019"
output: pdf_document
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
# Overview

This is an example of an ordinary code block with output that had to be included.

```{r mtcars, fig.width=3, fig.height=3}
head(mtcars)
```
# Test results in detail

The test results follow fully automated in detail.

```{r mtcars2, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, results="asis"}
invisible(sapply(tail(seq(mtcars), -2), function(i) {
  fo <- reformulate(names(mtcars)[i], response="mpg")
  s <- summary(do.call("lm", list(fo, quote(mtcars))))
  cat("\n## Model", i - 2, "\n")
  sapply(1:19, function(j) 
    cat(paste0("`", ". ", capture.output(s)[j]), "`  \n"))
  cat("  \n")
  }))
```

***Note:*** This is a concluding remark to show that we still can do other stuff afterwards.
````

### Produces:

(*Note:* Site 3 omitted)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to embed this solution into a longer R-script which on the one hand can be rendered by rmarkdown and on the other hand can be run step by step in the console?

Comment: @Tom Yes, sure, the only effect is that it produces the two files (`*.Rmd` and `*.pdf`), you could comment out the lines in order to prevent it temporarily, though.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the second, extended solution, which will be easy to incorporate into production. Since no one came up with a more straightforward way of doing what I'm looking for, this elaborate solution seems to reflect the current state of possibilities of rmarkdown. You have well earned the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

### Context

I was hit by the same need as that of OP when trying to generate multiple plots in a loop, but one of them would apparently crash the graphical device (because of **unpredictable** bad input) even when called using `try()` and prevent all the remaining figures from being generated. I needed really independent code blocks, like in the proposed solution.

### Solution

I've thought of preprocessing the source file before it was passed to `knitr`, preferably inside R, and found that the `jinjar` package was a good candidate. It uses a dynamic template syntax based on the Jinja2 templating engine from Python/Django. There are no syntax clashes with document formats accepted by R Markdown, but the tricky part was integrating it nicely with its machinery.

My hackish solution was to create a wrapper `rmarkdown::output_format()` that executes some code inside the `rmarkdown::render()` call environment to process the source file:

```r
preprocess_jinjar <- function(base_format) {
    if (is.character(base_format)) {
        base_format <- rmarkdown:::create_output_format_function(base_format)
    }

    function(...) {
        # Find the markdown::render() environment.
        callers <- sapply(sys.calls(), function(x) deparse(as.list(x)[[1]]))
        target <- grep('^(rmarkdown::)?render$', callers)
        target <- target[length(target)]  # render may be called recursively
        render_envir <- sys.frames()[[target]]

        # Modify input with jinjar.
        input_paths <- evalq(envir = render_envir, expr = {
            original_knit_input <- sub('(\\.[[:alnum:]]+)$', '.jinjar\\1', knit_input)
            file.rename(knit_input, original_knit_input)
            input_lines <- jinjar::render(paste(input_lines, collapse = '\n'))
            writeLines(input_lines, knit_input)

            normalize_path(c(knit_input, original_knit_input))
        })

        # Add an on_exit hook to revert the modification.
        rmarkdown::output_format(
                knitr = NULL,
                pandoc = NULL,
                on_exit = function() file.rename(input_paths[2], input_paths[1]),
                base_format = base_format(...),
        )
    }
}
```

Then I can call, for example:

```r
rmarkdown::render('input.Rmd', output_format = preprocess_jinjar('html_document'))
```

Or, more programatically, with the output format specified in the source file metadata as usual:

```r
html_jinjar <- preprocess_jinjar('html_document')
rmarkdown::render('input.Rmd')
```

Here is a minimal example for `input.Rmd`:

````yaml
---
output:
  html_jinjar:
    toc: false
---

{% for n in [1, 2, 3] %}
# Section {{ n }}

```{r block-{{ n }}}
print({{ n }}**2)
```
{% endfor %}
````

### Caveats

1. *It's a hack.* This code depends on the internal logic of `markdown::render()` and likely there are edge cases where it won't work. Use at your own risk.
2. For this solution to work, the output format contructor **must** be called by `render()`. Therefore, evaluating it before passing it to `render()` will fail:

```r
render('input.Rmd', output_format = 'html_jinja')  # works
render('input.Rmd', output_format = html_jinja)    # works
render('input.Rmd', output_format = html_jinja())  # fails
```

This second limitation could be circumvented by putting the preprocessing code inside the `pre_knit()` hook, but then it would only run after other output format hooks, like `intermediates_generator()` and other `pre_knit()` hooks of the format.

Comment: This also answers at least these two older questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33269675 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/46903792. But I posted it here as there was already a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to comment @jay.sf's (wonderful) answer due to a lack of reputation.

I am not sure if it can be of any help for anyone but I wrapped the `...capture.output(s)[j]...` part into a general function called `print_summary_loop` in the code below.

Here is an example of code:

````
    ---
    title: "Untitled"
    output:
      html_document:
        toc: true
        toc_float: true
        number_sections: true
        theme: united
    ---
    
    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = F, message = F, warning = F)
    library(datasets)
    ``` 
    
    ```{r initialisation}
    
    print_summary_loop = function(s){
      length_element <- length(capture.output(s))
      sapply(1:length_element, function(j) cat(paste0("`", ". ", capture.output(s)[j]), "`  \n"))
    }
    
    ``` 
    
    ```{r dummy_function_creation}
    
    dummy_function = function(){
      
      cat("# This is a test\n\n")
      
      m <- lm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)
      s <- summary(m)
      invisible(print_summary_loop(s))
      cat("\n\n")
      
    }
    
    ```
    
    ```{r results='asis'}
    dummy_function()
    ```
````