# How to print formated (kable) tables from a list of dataframes?

Tags: r, list, knitr, kable

I have a list composed of dataframes and I want to print each list element as a knitr table on my Rmarkdown file. However, I need to format the cells on each dataframe before passing them to kable().

Basically I need to format the background of the cell in each dataframe according to one condition (red if cell value is 1, white if it is zero) and them print each dataframe as a table (booktabs style).

I am using the following code, but the tables are not formatted using the booktabs option:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)


df1 <- data.frame("2016"=c(0,0,1,1), "2017"=c(1,1,1,1), "2018"=c(0,0,1,0), "2019"=c(1,0,0,0))
 
df2 <- data.frame("2016"=c(0,1,0,1), "2017"=c(1,0,0,1), "2018"=c(1,0,1,0), "2019"=c(1,0,1,1))
   

rownames(df1) <- c("sp1", "sp2", "sp3", "sp4")
rownames(df2) <- c("sp1", "sp2", "sp3", "sp4")

df.list <- list(df1,df2)

map(df.list, ~.x %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~cell_spec(., "html", background = ifelse(.x==1,  "red","white"), color = ifelse(.x==1, "red","white")))) %>% kable("html",  escape = F, booktabs = TRUE))
```

In my chunk options I have:

`{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, eval=TRUE, results = "asis"}`

It seems the options in `kable` are not being evaluated...

Any hints?

Thanks in advance:

Pedro Neves

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58283042/r-markdown-output-test-results-in-loop) help you answering your question?

Comment: Hi Tom: I don't think it does, or at least, I cannot apply it to my data.
I'll keep looking for options, but I seem to be close with my approach (if I can just figure out what is wrong in my code....

Comment: Not quite a solution, @PedroNeves, but here's (I hope) a start:
`df1 %>%
  mutate_all(~cell_spec(.x, background = ifelse(.x == 1, "red","white"))) %>%
  kable(escape = F, booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be mixing html and LaTeX.

The `booktabs` argument is for LaTeX outputs. So this may be what you are looking for:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r include=FALSE}

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(kableExtra)


df1 <- data.frame("2016"=c(0,0,1,1), "2017"=c(1,1,1,1), "2018"=c(0,0,1,0), "2019"=c(1,0,0,0))
 
df2 <- data.frame("2016"=c(0,1,0,1), "2017"=c(1,0,0,1), "2018"=c(1,0,1,0), "2019"=c(1,0,1,1))

rownames(df1) <- c("sp1", "sp2", "sp3", "sp4")
rownames(df2) <- c("sp1", "sp2", "sp3", "sp4")

df.list <- list(df1,df2)

```


   

```{r results='asis'}

map(df.list, ~.x |>  mutate(across(everything(), ~cell_spec(., "latex", background = ifelse(.x==1,  "red","white"), color = ifelse(.x==1, "red","white")))) |>  
      kbl(escape = FALSE,
            booktabs = TRUE))

```
````

With the following output:

[image]

Note: numerical variables in the call to `data.frame()` are 'automatically' given "syntactically valid" names. So there may be a bit of tidying up to do or use `tibble()` if you want the year as the variable name.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Peter. This helps a great deal.