# Using a for loop with knitr::kable and kableExtra::add_header_above

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

I am using **R version 3.5.2**.

I would like to **evaluate a string in a `kable` function**, but I am having some issues. Normally, I can pass a string through a for loop using the `get` function but in the `kableExtra::add_header_above` function I get the following error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:"print(kable(df4,"html", col.names = c("zero","one")) %>% add_header_above(c(get("string") ="
```

I have tried a handful of techniques like creating a string outside of the kable function and calling it, using page breaks and print statements in the knit loop and trying the `eval` function as well. I have also added result ="asis" as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36373630/how-to-create-a-loop-that-includes-both-a-code-chunk-and-text-with-knitr-in-r)

Here is a reproducible example:

````
```{r  results="asis"}    
library("knitr")
    library("kableExtra")

    df1 <- mtcars %>% dplyr::select(am,vs)

    df1a <- df1 %>% mutate(type = "A")
    df1b <- df1 %>% mutate(type = "B")
    df1c <- df1 %>% mutate(type = "C")

    df2 <- rbind(df1a,df1b,df1c)

    vector <- as.vector(unique(df2$type))

    for (variable in vector) {

      df3 <- df2 %>% filter(type == (variable))

      df4 <- table(df3$am,df3$vs)

    print(kable(df4,"html", col.names = c("zero","one")) %>%
      add_header_above(c(get("string") = 3)))

    }
```
````

Ideally, I would like the header of the table to have the string name from the column `type`. Below is an example of what I want it to look it:

```
print(kable(df4,"html", col.names = c("zero","one")) %>%
  add_header_above(c("A" = 3)))
```

I understand that the `knitr` function needs to be treated differently than regular R when using loops as found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36373630/how-to-create-a-loop-that-includes-both-a-code-chunk-and-text-with-knitr-in-r) solution but I am still struggling to get the string to be evaluated correctly. Perhaps because the function requires a vecotr input, it is not evalauting it as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define your header as a vector. The name of the header should be the names of the vector and the value of the vector would be the number of columns the header will use. 
The loop in the code should look like this:

```
for (variable in vector) {
  df3 <- df2 %>% filter(type == (variable))
  df4 <- table(df3$am,df3$vs)
  header_temp = 3
  names(header_temp) = get("variable")
  print(kable(df4,"html", col.names = c("zero","one")) %>%
    add_header_above(header_temp))
}
```

So first I define the number of columns the of the header in the variable `header_temp` and then i assign a name to it.

Comment: Interesting, how you you define what columns you want your header to be over specific columns without stating something like “header_temp = 2”

Comment: @Yoganium  If you mean something like the header being in the first 2 columns and not in the third you will have to create a vector that the elements sum the number of columns you have. And then add a string `" "` so there is no header. Continuing with the example it is something like this: `header_temp = c(2,1)`
  `names(header_temp) = c(get("variable")," ")`

Comment: Brilliant! That makes complete sense!