# How to make multiple plots with different heights in R markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am using Rmarkdown to automate generating a bunch of plots. I have code like:

````
```{r make_plots}
for (a_ggplot in a_bunch_of_ggplots()) {
    print(a_ggplot)
}
```
````

I'd like to make the plots different heights.  Normally I'd set the height with `fig.height` in the chunk header.  I tried using a vector for `fig.height` without success.  (I think it just used the last value.)

How do I make the plots different heights?

Also, I'll want to add some document headers.  I'm planning on trying technique from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36381976/34935) (generating raw markdown and using `results='asis'`).  Bonus points if your solution is compatible with it!

**EDIT**: Perhaps I could `ggsave` the plots as images, then use [include_graphics](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/r-code.html#figures).  Seems hacky.  Worse, it'll rasterize them so they can't be zoomed in on.  But, it's a thought.

Answer (score 1):

Best to use .pdfs here, since the format is designed for not to change when zooming. You simply could use the `for` loop or probably better `Map` to, first, create your plots, and, second, to produce "as-is" LaTeX code using `cat`. I'm using base plots here, I'm sure, you can also do this with `ggplot2`. Around the `Map` we wrap an `invisible` to omit console output.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
- \usepackage{lipsum}  % just used for sample loremipsum text
---

\lipsum[1]

```{r plots, echo=FALSE, results="asis"}

what <- rep("AirPassengers", 4)  ## mimicking multiple plots

invisible(Map(function(w) {
  pdf(file=paste0(w, ".pdf"))
  plot(get(w))
  dev.off()
}, what))

heights <- c(2, 4, 6, 8)  ## define heights for each plot

invisible(Map(function(w, h) cat(
"
\\begin{figure}[ht]
\\includegraphics[height=", paste0(h, "cm"), "]{", paste0(w, ".pdf"), "}
\\caption{", w, "}\\label{fig:", w, "}
\\end{figure}
", sep=""), what, heights))

```

\lipsum[1]
````

### Produces:

[image]

If you really only want different heights, you can specify the dimensions in the first `Map` call, e.g. using a second argument for the width, and use constant height/width in the second one.

Comment: This seems great, thank you. I already implemented my "hack" above, but I will try this soon!