# Create code snippets for various languages in rmardown programmatically

Tags: r, r-markdown

I try to create Code snippet programmatically through a provided Parameter but Keep the target programming language dynamic.

What i tried:
Following https://stackoverflow.com/a/64855295/8538074
i know i could use `opts <- knitr::opts_chunk$get()`
which will include an engine `opts$engine` which could be tried
to bet set to "SQL".

I guess that sthg like that should work because of:
https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/115-engine-sql.md
https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/115-engine-sql.Rmd

(but i would need to render it from code since i handover the corresponding code string via the params of the rmarkdown file)

**My best try:**

````
---
title: "xx"
output: html_document
params:
  code: list(language = "SQL", code_string = "SELECt * FROM tbl LIMIT 15")
---
   

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
hook <- knitr::hooks_html()$source
opts <- knitr::opts_chunk$get()

language <- params$code$code$language
opts$engine <- language

code_string <- params$code$code_string
cat(hook(code_string, options = opts))

```
````

Comment: First of all there are some errors in your code. Parse the output parameter first just like I answered on the other question: `chunks <- eval(parse(params$code))`. Then you can access `chunks$language` and `chunks$code_string`.
I get the error to install highlight by Andre simon when I render the document. You can then try that or set `opts$highglight <- FALSE`.

Comment: you are right, thanks. I add a self answer in case someone Need it. or would of Course upvote and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Martin´s comment:

````
---
title: "xx"
output: html_document
params:
  code: list(language = "SQL", code_string = "SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 15")
---
   

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r, results = 'asis', echo = F}
chunks <- eval(parse(text = params$code))
hook <- knitr::hooks_html()$source
opts <- knitr::opts_chunk$get()

opts$highlight <- FALSE
code_string <- chunks$code_string
cat(hook(code_string, options = opts))

```
````