# Print r comments in a loop in markdown

Tags: r, comments, r-markdown

I am using a for loop to generate model results and printing them in r markdown. To keep it tidy it would be nice to print comments before printing the model result.

Is there a way to print commented text behind hashtags in R?

e.g.

```
for(i in c(1:10)){
#this is the number
print(i)}
```

vs

```
#this is the number
print(1)
#this is the number
print(2)
#this is the number
print(3)
#this is the number
print(4)
```

Comment: This looks helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178831/generate-markdown-comments-within-for-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to try to print comment in my opinion. You can use `cat("this is the number", i, "\n")` within your loop. Eg:

```
for (i in 1:5)
  cat("this is number", i, "\n")

this is number 1 
this is number 2 
this is number 3 
this is number 4 
this is number 5
```

`message` instead of `cat`, tends to be preferred as we can easily get rid of them with `suppressMessages` or, better, `message=FALSE` in knitr/rmarkdown [chunks](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_rcodechunks.html).