# Generate both markdown comments and html wigets in a loop rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, dygraphs, flexdashboard

I'm trying to generate a flexdashboard, creating each page from within a loop and with each of the generated pages containing a `dygraph` (although any HTML widget ought to behave the same).

I have looked extensively and it seems that `rmarkdown` comments can be generated using `cat("title")` (as per the solution here: [generate markdown comments within for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178831/generate-markdown-comments-within-for-loop)).

The HTML widgets on the other hand only behave nicely if you use `htmltools::tagList()` (as per the solution here:[For loop over dygraph does not work in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30509866/for-loop-over-dygraph-does-not-work-in-r)).

I dont have working code to share, but this broadly gives the picture of what I am hoping to achieve:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(downloadedData)){
fund_NAVS <- downloadedData[,i] #this is an xts object
fund_NAVS <- fund_NAVS[!is.na(fund_NAVS)]
cat("pageTitle")
cat("===================================== \n")
cat("Row\n")
cat("------------------------------------- \n")
cat("### Page title")
dygraph(fund_NAVS)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible right now (see https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/issues/80).

Comment: I was able to get something working. I responded to the github discussion above but will also repost my answer here.

Answer (score 2):

I've been able to get this to partially work using `pander::pandoc.header`. However, getting content (plots and HTML objects) to actually show up in the final HTML file is a different story.

````
---
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    source: embed
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r results='asis'}

library(pander)

pages <- 5
cols <- 2
sections <- 3

for (p in 1:pages) {

  pandoc.header(paste("Page", p), level = 1)

  for (c in 1:cols) {

    pandoc.header(paste("Column", c), level = 2)

    for (s in 1:sections) {

      pandoc.header(paste("Section", s), level = 3)
      cat("hi")
      pandoc.p("")

    }

  }

}


```
````

Comment: Going to revise this because you can simply use different header levels as a replacement for the `===` and `---` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to autogenerate content by building r chunks explicitly then kniting them inline with `r paste(knitr::knit(text = out))`. This amazing line of code was found in an [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729415/generate-dynamic-r-markdown-blocks/21730473#comment65652301_21730473).

In my case, I wanted to produce a series of graphs, each with a separate tab, with different content. Each graph was similar but there were numerous (about 15) and I didn't want to copy/paste all of the separate chunks.

[Here is a gist you can download](https://gist.github.com/dantonnoriega/61559f39c06df92cca1f594bc63bcb8f) of a more simple example. (**The code is also below but note that I add `\` before each chunk so that it rendered as a single block of code so remove the `\` before running.**) I built a much more complicated function to build graphs, but the idea of the R chunks can be carried forward to any list object containing htmlwidgets as elements.

````
---
title: "Loop to Auto Build Tabs Containing htmlwidgets"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

\```{r setup, echo =FALSE, eval = TRUE}
library(tidyverse)
library(flexdashboard)
library(highcharter)

labels <- mtcars %>% names # these will serve as labels for each tab

# create a bunch of random, nonsensical line graphs
hcs <- purrr::map(.x = mtcars, ~highcharter::hchart(mtcars, y = .x, type = 'line')) %>%
    setNames(labels) # assign names to each element to use later as tab titles
\```

Page
====================

Column {.tabset .tabset-fade}
-----------------------------

<!-- loop to build each tabs (in flexdashboard syntax) -->
<!-- each element of the list object `out` is a single tab written in rmarkdown -->
<!-- you can see this running the next chunk and typing `cat(out[[1]])` -->

\```{r, echo = FALSE, eval = TRUE}

out <- lapply(seq_along(hcs), function(i) {

  a1 <- knitr::knit_expand(text = sprintf("### %s\n", names(hcs)[i])) # tab header, auto extracts names of `hcs`
  a2 <- knitr::knit_expand(text = "\n```{r}") # start r chunk
  a3 <- knitr::knit_expand(text = sprintf("\nhcs[[%d]]", i)) # extract graphs by "writing" out `hcs[[1]]`, `hcs[[2]]` etc. to be rendered later
  a4 <- knitr::knit_expand(text = "\n```\n") # end r chunk

  paste(a1, a2, a3, a4, collapse = '\n') # collapse together all lines with newline separator

})

\```

<!-- As I mentioned in the SO post, I don't quite understand why it has to be -->
<!-- 'r paste(knitr::knit(...)' vs just 'r knitr::knit(...)' but hey, it works -->

`r paste(knitr::knit(text = paste(out, collapse = '\n')))`
````